# DirectShow/C++. Adding subtitles during video capture

Tags: c++, directshow

I need to do the following:

1. Capture video from USB camera and write it to the file.
2. Add changing subtitles during capture (with date and time and some other information).

I wonder if it is possible in DirectShow. I found some information that VMR9 Render can be used for adding text but nothing specific. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DirectVobSub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectVobSub). That should help.

Comment: From the description: "DirectVobSub is a direct show filter, which can be used to display subtitle files during playback in a software player. The subtitles are not hardencoded to the video file". But I need to add hard subtitles during capture :(